# \cs{} command in l3doc does not respect \DoNotIndex?

Tags: l3doc

Consider this TeX file (yes, I know it's highly unusual to not use dtx for this.)

```
%%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\fvset{gobble=0,tabsize=4,frame=single,numbers=left,numbersep=3pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
\GetFileInfo{\jobname.tex}
 \DoNotIndex{\endlinechar,\newcommand}

\title{\pkg{somenewpackage} --- Description
\thanks{This file describes version \fileversion, last revised \filedate.}
}
\author{user202729%
%\thanks{E-mail: (not set)}
}
\date{Released \filedate}

\maketitle


\section{Motivation}


The braces around \verb+{\data}+ is optional; however, in the unlikely case if \cs{endlinechar} has the \enquote{letter} catcode, it might be absorbed and gives unexpected result.

\cs{mycommand}

    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\dummyMacro}{}
%    \end{macrocode}


\StopEventually{%
  \PrintChanges
  \PrintIndex
}
\Finale
\end{document}
```

Without the `\DoNotIndex`, the `\endlinechar`, `\mycommand` (appear in `\cs{...}`),
and `\newcommand` (appear in `macrocode` block) is included in the index.

With it, the `\newcommand` disappear but `\endlinechar` remains.

What is going on? (needless to say I don't see this in l3doc manual) & what should I do?

(actually that `\cs{...}` should probably be `\tn`, in retrospect. Either way, the problem persists)

I can see a few options

- use `|\endlinechar|` or `"\endlinechar"` instead of `\cs{endlinechar}` to typeset it? (... by the way this appear to be another undocumented thing in l3doc that it automatically make `|` and `"` shortverb...?)
- just deal with it?
- anything else?

Comment: On the other hand if `ltxdoc` instead of `l3doc` class is used, neither is included in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's simply not supported.

The command `\DoNotIndex` is inherited from the `doc` package, but (in my opinion) the documentation can easily be wrongly understood:

> [image: quote of doc package documentation]

"Those names won't show up in the index" only applies for the "every new macro name used within a `macrocode` or `macrocode*` environment". Other index entries e.g. produced by `\index` command, or directly written to the index file, won't be covered.

---

The current implementation (in [this version of l3doc.dtx](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/89a6e9cb4ad2a477608db9a7fdfd032d7734feb6/l3kernel/l3doc.dtx)) of `\cs` consist of

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \cs  { O{} m }
  { \@@_cmd:no {#1} { \c_backslash_str #2 } }

[...]

\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_cmd:nn #1#2
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l_@@_cmd_noindex_bool
    \bool_set_true:N \l_@@_cmd_replace_bool
    \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_cmd_index_tl { \q_no_value }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_cmd_module_tl { \q_no_value }

[...]

% Indexing.
%    \begin{macrocode}
    \bool_if:NT \l_@@_allow_indexing_bool
     {
      \bool_if:NF \l_@@_cmd_noindex_bool
       {
        \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_@@_cmd_index_tl
          {
            \__kernel_tl_set:Nx \l_@@_cmd_tl
              { \c_backslash_str \exp_not:o { \l_@@_cmd_index_tl } }
          }
        \exp_args:No \@@_key_get:n { \l_@@_cmd_tl }
        \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_@@_cmd_module_tl
          {
            \__kernel_tl_set:Nx \l_@@_index_module_tl
              { \tl_to_str:N \l_@@_cmd_module_tl }
          }
        \@@_special_index_module:ooonN
          { \l_@@_index_key_tl }
          { \l_@@_index_macro_tl }
          { \l_@@_index_module_tl }
          { usage }
          \l_@@_index_internal_bool
       }
     }

[...]
     
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_special_index_module:nnnnN #1#2#3#4#5
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{arguments}
% \item key
% \item macro
% \item module
% \item index `type' (\texttt{main}/\texttt{usage}/\emph{etc.})
% \item boolean whether internal command
% \end{arguments}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {
    \use:x
      {
        \exp_not:n { \@@_special_index_aux:nnnnnn {#1} {#2} }
          \tl_if_empty:nTF {#3}

[...]

\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_special_index_aux:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{arguments}
% \item key
% \item macro
% \item index subheading string
% \item index subheading text
% \item index subheading suffix (appended to both arg 3 and 4)
% \item index `type' (\texttt{main}/\texttt{usage}/\emph{etc.})
% \end{arguments}
%    \begin{macrocode}
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_@@_index_escaped_key_tl {#1}
    \@@_quote_special_char:N \l_@@_index_escaped_key_tl
    \@@_special_index_set:Nn \l_@@_index_escaped_macro_tl {#2}
    \str_if_eq:onTF { \@currenvir } { macrocode }
      { \@@_index_codeline_hc:nn }
      {
        \str_case:nnF {#6}
          {
            { main }  { \@@_index_codeline_hc:nn }
            { usage } { \@@_index_page_hc:nn }
          }
          { \@@_target: \@@_index_page_hc:nn }
      }
      {
        \tl_if_empty:nF { #3 #4 #5 }
          { #3 #5 \actualchar #4 #5 \levelchar }
        \l_@@_index_escaped_key_tl
        \actualchar
        {

[...]


\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_index_codeline_hc:nn #1#2
  {
    \immediate\write\@indexfile
      {
        \string \indexentry { #1 \encapchar hdclindex{\the\c@HD@hypercount}{#2} }
          { MMMMV - \filesep \int_use:N \c@CodelineNo - MMMD - \the\c@HD@hypercount - M }
      }
  }
```

As can be seen, the index entry is written directly without consulting the index exclude list (refer to section 3.7 of `doc` package documentation).

---

In summary, just use `|...|` then. There's little loss in semantic meaning of the source code in my opinion. (although if you really want you could as well patch the `\__codedoc_cmd:nn` to consult the `\index@excludelist` list)